# How to pivot a single cell dataframe

Tags: r, tidyr, tibble

I have encountered such a simple challenge, and yet don't know how to do this properly.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)


# I have this single-cell dataframe

tibble::tribble(~red,
                "apple")

## # A tibble: 1 x 1
##   red  
##   <chr>
## 1 apple
```

But being `red` is a property of the variable `fruit`, which `apple` is one observation of. Therefore, I want my data to look like:

```r
# Desired Output:

## # A tibble: 1 x 2
##   fruit red  
##   <chr> <lgl>
## 1 apple TRUE
```

So I tried a clunky method, which seems not best practice:

```r
tibble::tribble(~red,
                "apple") %>%
  mutate(is_red = TRUE) %>%
  rename(fruit = red, red = is_red)
```

Is there a proper way to do it? Perhaps by pivoting rather than mutating and renaming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R you would do:

```
table(stack(df))>0
       ind
values   red
  apple TRUE
```

And if you need it as a dataframe:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(df)) > 0)
       red
apple TRUE
```

Note that this would work even when  you have multiple colors and fruis:
eg:

```
df1=data.frame(red= 'apple', green = 'apple', orange = 'orange', yellow = 'banana') 

as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(df1)) > 0)
         red green orange yellow
apple   TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
banana FALSE FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
orange FALSE FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
```

Comment: This is really neat. I wonder if there's a way to pipe this using `%>%`. Because this is part of a greater workflow, I try my best not to assign additional data objects along the way. Right now, running `df %>% as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(.)) > 0)` throws an error. Do you have an idea how to make this work with `%>%`?

Comment: @Emman `df %>% stack() %>%table() %>% as.data.frame()%>%is_greater_than(0)` should work or if you want, you could do `df %>% {as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(.)) > 0)}`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pivot_longer` and `mutate` the 'red' to logical `TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = names(.), values_to = 'fruit') %>%
     mutate(!! names(df1) := TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  red   fruit
#  <lgl> <chr>
#1 TRUE  apple
```

---

Or another option is `cur_column`

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~cur_column(), .names = "fruit"),
         !! names(df1) := TRUE)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#   red   fruit
#   <lgl> <chr>
#1 TRUE  red
```

Comment: Thanks. But can't we pass the name of the column to `names_to`, rather than hardcoding the "red" word?

Comment: @Emman I updated the post.  But, this may not be a general solution i.e when you have more columns and rows