# Wrangling nested data to dataframe: different types of nested data - logical and named list

Tags: r, list, purrr, tibble

I have data that looks like this:

```r
my_list <-
  list(
    my_main_var_isFoodVar = TRUE,
    my_main_var_VarNameChosenValues = list(key = "fruit", values = c("banana", "apple", "kiwi"))
  )

## $my_main_var_isFoodVar
## [1] TRUE

## $my_main_var_VarNameChosenValues
## $my_main_var_VarNameChosenValues$key
## [1] "fruit"

## $my_main_var_VarNameChosenValues$values
## [1] "banana" "apple"  "kiwi"
```

And I'm trying to organize this data in a data frame, such that it will describe a variable called `fruit`, which is a "food variable" (and hence `isFoodVar = TRUE`), and has certain values `banana`, `apple`, and `kiwi`. I also know this is my "main variable" because it has  `$**my_main_var**_VarNameChosenValues$key` for `fruit`.

So the **desired output** should look like:

```r
library(tibble)

tribble(~var_name, ~is_main_var, ~is_food_var, ~var_values,
        "fruit", TRUE, TRUE, c("banana", "apple", "kiwi"))

##   var_name is_main_var is_food_var var_values
##   <chr>    <lgl>       <lgl>       <list>    
## 1 fruit    TRUE        TRUE        <chr [3]> 

## and we can see the `var_values` if we unnest_longer(var_values):

##  var_name is_main_var is_food_var var_values
##   <chr>    <lgl>       <lgl>       <chr>     
## 1 fruit    TRUE        TRUE        banana    
## 2 fruit    TRUE        TRUE        apple     
## 3 fruit    TRUE        TRUE        kiwi
```

### My insufficient attempt

The only part I would know how to tackle is for extracting that `fruit` is the "main variable".
(Thanks to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65498649/6105259))

```r
library(dplyr)

my_list$my_main_var_VarNameChosenValues[1] %>%
  {as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(.)) > 0)} %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "var_name") %>%
  rename(is_main_var = key)

##   var_name is_main_var
##   <chr>    <lgl>      
## 1 fruit    TRUE
```

And even this is not good enough, because it isn't even looking for the string `my_main_var`. So really, I have no idea how to organize everything nicely as demonstrated. I'll be thankful for any help.

---

#### EDIT

---

Given @Tjebo's comment, I'm updating my data and providing some more context and complexity, as well as my own clunky (and undesired) method of solving the problem.

```r
my_list_2 <-
  list(
    my_main_var_isFoodVar = TRUE,
    my_main_var_VarNameChosenValues = list(key = "fruit", values = c("banana", "apple", "kiwi")),
    other_var_var_isFoodVar = TRUE,
    other_var_varNameChosenValues = list(key = "vegetable", values = c("tomato", "cauliflower", "cabbage"))
  )
```

Now I convert to data.frame and extract info only from `my_main_var` columns.

```r
my_list_as_df <- as.data.frame(my_list_2)

pulled_var_name <- 
  my_list_as_df %>%
  select(starts_with("my_main_var")) %>%
  select(ends_with("key")) %>%
  unique() %>%
  pull()

pulled_var_values <- 
  my_list_as_df %>%
  select(starts_with("my_main_var")) %>%
  select(ends_with("values")) %>%
  pull()

pulled_is_food_var <- 
  my_list_as_df %>%
  select(starts_with("my_main_var")) %>%
  select(ends_with("isFoodVar")) %>%
  unique() %>%
  pull()


tibble(var_name = pulled_var_name,
       var_values = list(pulled_var_values),
       is_food_var = pulled_is_food_var,
       is_main_var = TRUE)

##   var_name var_values is_food_var is_main_var
##   <chr>    <list>     <lgl>       <lgl>      
## 1 fruit    <chr [3]>  TRUE        TRUE
```

Although this gets the job done, it's a bad piece of code. It's repetitive and clunky. But it shows the output I hope for: a summary table for the main variable of interest.

Comment: You're basically asking two questions there. Also, your example seems to lack complexity - how can the fruits *not* have "$**my_main_var**_VarNameChosenValues$key" ? Is there another option? I'd suggest separating those questions and ask one at a time

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure this question should be split up further, given that it's the lowest data "unit" I'm dealing with. With this data, having `my_main_var` is the basis for knowing that `fruit` is the main var. There are other options outside the scope of this, but I didn't include them because it would be even more unclear.

Comment: @Tjebo, I edited the post to address your points. I hope it's clearer now. Thanks!

Comment: so, do you only want to extract the data for your "main_var"?

Comment: Yes, and have it organized in that summary table

Comment: updated my answer accordingly. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Something like tidyr::nest should help:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

my_list_2 <-
  list(
    my_main_var_isFoodVar = TRUE,
    my_main_var_VarNameChosenValues = list(key = "fruit", values = c("banana", "apple", "kiwi")),
    other_var_var_isFoodVar = TRUE,
    other_var_varNameChosenValues = list(key = "vegetable", values = c("tomato", "cauliflower", "cabbage"))
  )

data.frame(my_list_2) %>%
  select(starts_with("my_main_var")) %>%
  nest(value = contains(".values")) %>% # this is your desired output
  mutate(value = paste(unlist(value), collapse = "," )) # if you want character vector rather than list 
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   my_main_var_isFoodVar my_main_var_VarNameChosenValues.key value            
#>   <lgl>                 <chr>                               <chr>            
#> 1 TRUE                  fruit                               banana,apple,kiwi
```

Comment: updated based on question update to select "main_var" only